# Find two maximal domains, one simply connected and one not, for $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem:

Give two different maximal domains in the complex plane (one simply connected and one not simply connected) for $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+1}$. Explain how $f$ is defined and why the definition of $f$ cannot be extended to even one additional point in the complex plane outside of the maximal domain.

I believe this means we need to find two domains such that $f$ is holomorphic on each and such that $f^2(z)=z^2+1$ on each. My guess is that the domains we're interested in are $\mathbb{C}\setminus {\{ci:|c|\leq 1}\}$ (not simply connected) and $\mathbb{C}\setminus ({\{ic:c\geq 1}\}\cup {\{ic:c\leq -1}\})$ (simply connected). My thought is that we will eventually define $f(z)=e^{\displaystyle{\frac
{1}{2}\int_{\gamma_{a,z}}\frac{1}{z-i}+\frac{1}{z+i}}}dz$, where $a$ is a fixed point in our domain and $z$ is any point in the domain. However I'm unsure how to define the domains to get to this point. After defining such an $f$, I believe the justification for why $f$ can't be extended will have to do with winding numbers. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I've seen questions like this before, the "can't be extended" part usual comes from showing that you get different limits as you approach points on a branch cut from different sides.

Comment: @JonathanZ Do you know how one would go about finding the domains?

Comment: Me, I'm really comfortable with doing branch cuts on $\sqrt z$, so I could just "move the origin" to get domains for each of $\sqrt {z-i}$ and $\sqrt {z+i}$. Then those functions could be multiplied, and we'd start having to use both branch cuts, but they'll probably cancel each out in some places.

Comment: Honestly, I seem to remember this function, or maybe the similar $\sqrt {z^2-1}$, as a fairly standard example of branch cuts that your average complex analysis book would work out in detail. If you're working from a text, I'd expect that there would be a fairly complete treatment of a similar function (there are a lot of details to work through, the first time you see it). Making sure you understand all the details of that would be my first step.

Comment: Unfortunately my professor just uses his own self contained handwritten lecture notes, do you have any good complex book recommendations?

Comment: You can take $f_1(z) = \sqrt{z^2+1}$  and $f_2(z) = z\sqrt{1+1/z^2}$ where the principal  root is used in both cases.

Comment: Sorry, haven't got a recommendation. I did this stuff a long time ago, and all the texts I used were just okay. And text books cost so much these days! Maybe Schaum's Outlines would have a good supplement? Sorry I can't help more with that.

Comment: Oh, and your updates is exactly the two examples I was thinking of. And in my previous comment I was imagining cuts along the imaginary axis, from either +I or -i, and going to either positive or negative imaginary infinity.

Comment: Have you seen the trick where we know that arg(sqrt (some expression)) jumps by $\pi$ when we cross a branch cut, but when we multiply two expressions their arg's add, and if your arg jumps by $2\pi$ then your function is actually continuous going over the cut?